# C++ Declaration is incompatible with method

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, class, compiler-errors

I have an issue with a class that I am implementing.

```
typedef enum
{
    YELLOW,
    GREEN,
    BLUE
} COLOUR;

class Stream
{
public:
    Stream();
    ~Stream();
    double getRate(COLOUR colour);
private:
    double yrate;
    double grate;
    double brate;
};

Stream::Stream()
{
    yrate = 2.2;
    grate = 3.3;
    brate = 4.4;
}

Stream::~Stream()
{
}

double Stream::getRate(COLOUR colour)
{
    double rate;
    switch(colour)
    {
    case YELLOW:
        rate = yrate;
        break;
    case GREEN:
        rate = grate;
        break;
    case BLUE:
        rate = brate;
        break;
    }
    return rate;
}
```

I am using Visual C++ 2010 Express, and I cannot compile this because the error is:
'Error: declaration is incompatible with "double Stream::getRate(COLOUR colour)"

Is there something I am missing, or some order that I have confused?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems to compile without a problem: http://codepad.org/OUS36Z3g

Comment: The more C++ way to write your enum is `enum COLOUR { ... };`. However, the code you've given compiles fine in all three versions of Visual Studio, which suggests the problem is a conflict in the code you didn't paste.

Comment: @kfsone I had this as a separate header file in a project, and even with nothing else including it, intellisense tells me of this error.

Comment: Yes, but this code itself is not the problem, there is possibly a definition of "COLOUR" or "getRate" somewhere else. Make a clean project, paste from your post into it, add a trivial main and compile. Then start adding in code from your project and see when it breaks.

Answer (score 1):

Write

```
enum COLOUR
{
    YELLOW,
    GREEN,
    BLUE
};
```

instead. The `typedef` idiom you're using (in an incomplete way) is for `C` compatibility which, from your tags, you don't need.

Comment: But in this case the OP shall write double getRate(enum COLOUR colour); or am I wrong?

Comment: Thats true, but, is this an answer?

Comment: @duDE, in C++, the `enum` before COLOUR in getRate is superfluous. In C it isn't.

Comment: Oh, I remember, that was in C :) Thanks! BTW, compiles like OP wrote without problem: http://codepad.org/OUS36Z3g